# How to share and embedded image on many RDLC Reports

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc, embedded-resource

I created an MDI application that shows some DataGridViews on different child Forms that are considered as separate application because they have access to different databases.

Those data need to be exported in PDF reports. I used the ReportViewer component inside a new MDI child form and I created a new Project on the solution that contains only the RDLC report files as embedded resources, associated to each application. This was done to avoid having an user accessible folder inside the program folder that contains each .RDLC file, for security reasons.

This is the files/folders structure of the VS Solution:

```
Solution
|
|_ Classes
| |
| |_ Library Project that contains all the classes used for Data Access...
|
|_ MDIMain
| |
| |_ The main application Project that contains some Core Classes and Forms...
|
|_ Reports (A DLL project that doesn't contain .cs code files, but only folders and RDLC reports)
  |
  |_ App1
  | |
  | |_ Report1.rdlc
  | |_ Report2.rdlc
  | |_ ...
  |
  |_ App2
    |
    |_ Report1.rdlc
    |_ ...
```

All works fine, but now I need to customize all my reports by inserting a logo, so an Image. So I need to add to every report the same image.

Looking on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251715(v=vs.90).aspx) documentation it seems that there're 3 kind of possible source for images:

- "Embedded": works only by embedding the image inside the single report file. But in my case this is not a valid soluition due to waste of storage.
- **"External": by specifing URL or path (what I'd like to do)**.
- "Database": specify the database field that contains the image.

The .rdlc files are referred and loaded inside the ReportViewer windows, by using the Reports.dll library as source using a "folder.filename" syntax.

```
/* 
 * reportSource variable is calculated dynamically with the selection on a ComboBox
 * that let the use choose a specific report.
 * The source format is like this: "Reports.AppNameFolder.Report1.rdlc"
 */

string reportSource = cmbReport.SelectedValue.ToString();
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("");
rds.Name = "DataSet";
rds.Value = _reportDataTable;

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Reports.dll");
UnmanagedMemoryStream reportStream = (UnmanagedMemoryStream)assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(reportSource);

reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(reportStream);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

So, if I want to create a folder that contains my images:

1. Where should I put it, with the certainty that then the folder is generated together with the output of the main project?
2. How can I do to keep the reference to the folder and images both in debug mode, and release mode, so when the program will be installed in the user client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following

in the image properties on the report

1. Image Source : Embedded
2. click import button and load the image

in this way, the RDLC will save the image as base64 inside of the file rdlc, you can view by open with xml editor from the solution explorer pane, and no need to worry about the location of the image.

another way if you want to load the image from the database for example, you can do the following

1. Image Source: Database
2. Use this field: [YourPropertyName]
3. Use this MIME type: image/jpeg
4. in the report dataset, add a byte[] column or property called YourPropertyName

**Last Note**, if the logo is common in all the reports you have, its recommended to add subreport called header that contains this logo and you put it in each report you have, this way if you want to change the logo later, you only need to change it in that header subreport.

you can view this [demo](http://screencast.com/t/T1ixvRWa) I prepared to show you how to achieve this ( to add a header report to your current report)

hope this will help you

Comment: Embedding the image inside each report is not a good solution. The Database solution is not valid too for my case. Your last suggest about a subreport used as header could be valid, but how should I implement that? I created a new Report and added to that the logo image. But then I cannot reference it from other reports...

Comment: @CheshireCat from the toolbox drag and drop subreport and place it in the target report, then right click this subreport object ( gray) => subreport properties, then put the name of the report "HeaderReport" for example under the Name and Use this report as a sub report text boxes and you are done

Comment: I didn't know about the `Subreport` component! Anyway, my reports have a Page Header which contains the logo, a title, a subtitle and the page/total number. If I understand correctly, the `Subreport` should be used like a `Panel` that contains all of these `TextBox` and `Image` controls. But if I try to drag the Subreport inside the Page Header it doesn't move. I think it's not possible to include a Subreport inside a Report header...

Comment: no, this subreport component you will configure it to be linked to the report that contains the images and titles, and to make this link, you should give this subreport the name of the report that contains header content, and to do so, after adding the component, right click on it and go to subreport properties and put the name of the report that contains the image and titles and page count in the 2 text boxes ( Name , use this report as a sub report) as i mentioned in the previous comment

Comment: @CheshireCat, remove the content from the Page header and put it in a separate report call it HeaderReport for example and put the sub report component in the page header and do as i mentioned before and link this component to the HeaderReport.rdlc, in the text boxed don't put the extension (.rdlc) just the name

Comment: I always get "Cannot find Header subreport in the specified path HeaderReport. Check if the subreport has been published and that the name is correct." Both main and sub report are inside the same folder. The names are correct. And the "Use this report as subreport" parameter has the correct value, so it is "HeaderReport".

Comment: @CheshireCat stay connected i will prepare a sample for you

Comment: @CheshireCat i don't think that i can find a better way to help you than this : check this screencast demo: http://screencast.com/t/T1ixvRWa

Comment: That was exactly what I've done. Maybe the problem is with my logic that loads the report using the MemoryStream. It's a bit different from yours. I'll try to make some changes... thanks! What if I want that the header subreport will be repeated on each page of the report, such as a Page Header does?

Comment: @CheshireCat I think you can use List for that and in the properties you can mark to repeat on each page